# Reset all global state?

Tags: javascript

I need to run two scripts in the browser which should not interfere with each other. Both allocate global variables and functions.

Is there a way to reset all global state in between script execution such that both scripts run basically in isolation from each other?

```
const f = 1;
// Reset global state
const f = 2;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.

This is one reason you should avoid using global variables.

Use [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) or [IIFEs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to limit the scope of the variables they create. Then having variables of the same name in different scripts won't cause a problem.

```html
<script type="module">
    const foo = 1;
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(`Script one foo is ${foo}`);
    }, 1000);
</script>

<script type="module">
    const foo = 2;
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(`Script two foo is ${foo}`);
    }, 750);
</script>
```

For the sake of comparison, here is the same code as regular scripts instead of modules where you get an error for redeclaring `const`:

```html
<script>
    const foo = 1;
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(`Script one foo is ${foo}`);
    }, 1000);
</script>

<script>
    const foo = 2;
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(`Script two foo is ${foo}`);
    }, 750);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [IIFEs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) for each script like this.

script1.js

```js
(() => {
  const f = 1;
})()
```

script2.js

```js
(() => {
  const f = 1;
})()
```

Comment: Or you could just use brackets. `{const f = 1;} {const f = 2;}`